# How to set file path to save a file in my local computer from java web application

Tags: java, swing

I have a java web application which use `EJB,Hibernate`. In my application I create some `.txt` file. I need to allow user to select a folder in computer that the `.txt` file should save. Ideally it should look like this

[image]

I do not want to select the "Save as type" part. Since this is a web application I need to add this functionality with a button click like "Browse save location". Can some one help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to make couple of changes in code as below:

Use JFileChooser for selecting file, this will enable file chooser

```
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser(); fileChooser.setDialogTitle("Choose a file");
```

Set Native Look and Feel, to get window's like look and feel. Make sure this code fragment is called from constructor/method from where panel is rendered.

```
  try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks.I want to add a a button like browse.When I click it the Jpanel should appear.

Comment: probably you need JFileChooser, something like this. JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    fileChooser.setDialogTitle("Choose a file");

Comment: I added but it does not opened the corresponding window like in the picture